# Create a route using a list of coordinates in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a list of lat,lon coordinates as result of tracking a bus. I'm showing the route using PolyLine to create a line to connect "the dots" but because of the accuracy these dots aren't exactly by the street, and when you zoom in it is more obvious.

What can I do to show the route by the street?

This is what I have right now (There are 2 lines because the bus did 2 turns. It won't show like this in the final product)
[image]

And this is what I need.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How many of these do you need to do?

Comment: @geocodezip routes? one at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for 'snap polyline to road using google maps api v3' for similar discussions.

There doesn't appear to be a straightforward API service to do this and you would need to reduce your route to significant changes in direction rather than every wiggle.

You might add a star to the issue in the 'Google Maps API bug reports and feature requests' database
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3824
and possibly add a new issue since your problem is somewhat different

Comment: This is a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reducing the polylines to the minimum number of waypoints required to make the DirectionsServide create the same route.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html) from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route/)

[example using coordinates rather than addresses](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)

Comment: It is a solution that I already considered but I was told that there is a "fastest way" using the API. Anyway, I'm gonna use this, thanks for the links! they are helpful