# Designing map routes for bicycles

Tags: google-maps, routes

I'm an avid bicycle rider and I like to create complex routes in my area sometimes for ease of riding, sometimes for difficult riding like lots of hills.

I used to be able to go to google maps and design a route with about 30 different points with most of the time the starting point and ending point being within feet of each other with the entire route up to 100 miles long. I then used to click/copy on the URL drop that into my application and extract all the turn points in Lat/Lon GPS points.

My application would then create a .GPX file with GPS points for turning left or right  with the help of OpenGPX to save to my Garmin eTrex. I would then save the route to MyPlaces and then download the .kml for the path of the riding route also to show up on the eTrex.

I haven't designed a long riding route since fall last year and now can only have 8 route changes, can't save the route to myPlaces any more nor download a .kml

Is there a reason why this has been turned off or changed? Can I get it back? Is there another way on google maps to design a route and get GPS points for turning directions? Even my older saved routes have had the change points removed if there was more than 8.

I'm a very well accomplished software developer and have looked through the API but didn't see much that would make this easy.

The only data I want is GPS points possibly the .kml and a easy way to design complex bicycle routes on the street up to 100 miles or so with starting and ending points mostly the same.

Comment: Sounds like you were using the Google Maps Javascript API v2 which was deprecated and turned off in 2010, replaced with a wrapper for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (which has a limitation of 8 waypoint for the free version, 23 waypoints with a business license).

Comment: [Possible workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route/15315945#15315945) using multiple directions requests, although hard to tell what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Gebweb tsp solver its a special application for the tsp problem but maybe it gives more then 8:http://gebweb.net/optimap/.