# google map directions , why my code won't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to draw path between multiple points on map. I use below code to draw path , but it won't work and won't draw any path. why and how can I solve this?

```
    var myTrip = [], waypts=[];    
                        myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(32.6384014, 51.65132887000004));
                        waypts.push({
                            location: new google.maps.LatLng(32.6384014, 51.65132887000004),
                            stopover: true
                        });

myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(32.63727025, 51.65345639999998));
                        waypts.push({
                            location: new google.maps.LatLng(32.63727025, 51.65345639999998),
                            stopover: true
                        });

myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(32.6367726, 51.65345639999998));
                        waypts.push({
                            location: new google.maps.LatLng(32.6367726, 51.65677270000003),
                            stopover: true
                        });                       

                    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
                    {
                        suppressMarkers: true,
                        suppressInfoWindows: true
                    });
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    var request = {
                        origin: myTrip[0],
                        destination: myTrip[myTrip.length - 1],
                        waypoints: waypts,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };
                    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        }
                    });
```

here is my jsfiddle code :
[jsfiddle geomap](https://jsfiddle.net/minamorsali/5tv2z1yt/12/)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The [posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vpr1dkxy/)

Comment: I provide my jsfiddle code. It work when points is statis , but when I fill points dynamically It wont work with waypoints in request

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.  How many waypoints? How do you "fill points dynamically"?

Comment: 15 points , I add points same as above static example code.

Comment: I think this problem cause of points count , when I decrease point numbers path draw successfully. How can I manage too many points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Google Maps polylines : issue in connecting all given GPS locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609872/javascript-google-maps-polylines-issue-in-connecting-all-given-gps-locations/27610234#27610234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is from the way points number , from google reference :
[google map developers reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

> The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Google Maps API for Work customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit directions.