# How to make custom routes for buses in google maps and how to make it accessible for user on my website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using google map custom routes for searching  local buses routes in the  city but unable to find any way/example to used it on my website please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route

Comment: Thanks d-datul1990